# How to rerun-useEffect() after dispatching an redux action in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm working on react native application with redux, The reducer looks something like this,

```
    reducer = {
      dataA: {},
      dataB: {},
      laoding: false,
      error: false
    }
```

I have created a redux action which will update dataA object in reducer. I called the action
from one of my react-native components in useEffect().

```
useEffect(() => {
 dispatch(dataA())
}, [])
```

I haven't passed any dependency array.

Everything works great, But from the same component where I explicitly dispatching an
action to update dataB object which will incur update the dataA from the backend itself.

I'm expecting that, whenever i dispatch an action explicitly to update the dataB, the useEffect
should re-run to get the latest updated object values from dataA object.

But it is not happening, Even I try to pass dataA object as dependency to useEffect, it going an
infinite loop of useEffect.

And also, dataB object consists boolean value which i want to display alert box when ever i dispatch an action to update dataB.

```
  dataB = {
   result: {
     success: true || false,
     Message: "Something"
    }
  }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you. you can try this :

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(dataA())
}, [dataB])
```

Answer (score 0):

It goes to infinite loop because you update `dataA` and give dependency `dataA` which calls this `useEffect` again and again. You could give `dataB` as dependency and this means whenever `dataB` changes call this `useEffect`.